# Ajust the position of autocomplete fields

Tags: 7, theming, ajax

I working with the theme base bootstrap and my problem is that in autocomplete fields it's a bit offside of position, see the screenshot.

How fix this ? I need this more to the left and below the textfield.

[image: screenshot]

Greetings.

Comment: Ever find a resolution?

Comment: Nop, is with css but I can't debug this, because is difficult when is ajax :(

Comment: Ok so I found some [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1218684) that is related. Do you have the field in a fieldset by chance? The way I ended up fixing mine is putting a position relative on the div containing the field.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a CSS positioning issue, whether it is caused by padding, margining, position, top, left, right, or bottom.

You should be able to use firebug or another developer tool like it to find what CSS is causing this and remove that CSS if it's your own CSS. Otherwise if the CSS is provided by contrib then you can use a more specific CSS selector and override the values.